# Linear programming of the Sinkhorn distance (entropy-regularized optimal transport)

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, linear-programming, entropy, optimal-transport

\begin{align}
\mathcal{W}_\epsilon(\alpha, \beta) =& \min_{\pi\in \Pi(\alpha\beta)} \int c(x,y) \mathrm{d}\pi(x,y) + \epsilon H(\pi) \\
=& \min_{\pi\in \Pi(\alpha\beta)} \int c(x,y) \mathrm{d}\pi(x,y) + \epsilon \int \pi(x,y) \ln \pi(x,y) 
\end{align}
How can the above formula for the Sinkhorn distance be expressed as a linear programming optimization problem?

Is the following correct?

$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
\min_\mathbf{x} \  \mathbf{c}^\top \mathbf{x} + \epsilon \mathbf{x}^\top \ln \mathbf{x}  \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}  =  \ \mathbf{b} \\
 \   \mathbf{x}  \geq \ \mathbf{0}
\end{array}$$

where $H(\pi) = \epsilon \mathbf{x}^\top \ln \mathbf{x}$ is the entropy term.

Comment: Correct in what sense? you have just written down an optimisation problem...

Comment: I'ved made an edit hope it helps

Comment: Why not use Sinkhorn?

Comment: you're saying the proposed linear program reflects the formula, but linear programming the formula with the Sinkhorn algorithm is completely different?